# The car is a "bit off" = the car is off the road? I'm a bit off = I'm a bit off topic?

Tags: usage

1. The car is a bit off → the car is off the road
2. I'm a bit off → I'm a bit off  topic

Can they be briefed/shortened like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

**A bit off** has an idiomatic meaning that means **not quite right**. For example:

> I'm feeling a bit off today = *I'm feeling a bit unwell today*

So in your examples:

*The car is a bit off* would mean *the car isn't quite working properly*.
*I'm a bit off* would probably be taken to mean *I'm a bit unwell*, but could be taken to mean *I'm a bit crazy*, depending on context and listener.

Comment: i see!  btw, +1 how do i say that? plus one? here in the comment bar when i type, the tip says don't comment with "+1" and "thanks".

Comment: @Cry-loRen Yes, you say it "plus one". And as you correctly notice, comments that say it are unnecessary, so should not be made ;)